# Como desabilitar o autocomplete de inputs do Google Chrome

Tags: input, autocompletar

**Estou ciente de que já existem outras perguntas como esta aqui na comunidade. No entanto, percebi que as soluções apontadas já não estão funcionando. E faz sentido, pois as respostas foram registradas no ano de 2015. De lá para cá muita coisa mudou e continua mudando.**

Para desabilitar o autocomplete dos inputs do formulário, apliquei os seguintes comandos, mas sem sucesso:

- Inclui o autocomplete="off" no form.
- Também fiz a inclusão via jquery.

A função autocomplete dos inputs continuam funcionando.

Poderiam me dar um auxílio?

Comment: Coloquei em negrito para ficar mais claro.

Comment: `autocomplete` não funciona para campos de usuário e senha e acredito que email tb, apenas para campos comuns de form

Comment: Ola. Tentou utilizar autocomplete="false" ao invés de autocomplete="off".